# NEST-Initiative: Disable simulation output

Tags: nest-simulator, nest-initiative

Is there a way to disable the output generated from NEST:

```
 ...
 94 %: network time: 38604.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1404
 94 %: network time: 38605.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1404
 94 %: network time: 38606.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1403
 94 %: network time: 38607.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1405
 94 %: network time: 38608.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1404
 94 %: network time: 38609.0 ms, realtime factor: 2.1404
```

that is generated by `nest.Simulate()`?

```
for t in range(int(Tsim/10000.)):
    nest.Simulate(Tsim)
```

Comment: btw, your loop seems very strange: for `Tsim<10000.` you never call nest.Simulate and for larger values, for example `Tsim = 38000` you simulate 38sec biological time three times, giving a total simulation of 114sec. That might not be what you intend.

Comment: @TerhorstD This was just to show how I produced the log-output I think since the question only asks how to disable it but thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the printing of time stamps in the kernel dictionary:

```
nest.SetKernelStatus({'print_time': False})
```

Regarding output in general, you might also be interested in setting the verbosity with `nest.set_verbosity()`. A level of 0 displays all messages, 100 suppresses all.